# R6034 (.exe) manifest error (On application start)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, manifest

I'm having this issue that I never, ever received before:

> R6034
>   An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library without using a manifest.
>   This is an unsupported way to load Visual C++ DLLs. You need to modify your application to build with a manifest.

I looked at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591.aspx

It didn't help. My projects also have the "Runtime Library: Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)" selected. I just don't have any other thing I can think of to get rid of this.

I'm also pretty sure this warning while compiling is part of it:

> warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

I'm using: 
"Windows 7",
"Visual Studio 2008"

Command Line:

> /nologo /outputresource:"....\bin\Release\world.exe;#1"

Comment: What manifest are you attaching to your executable?

Comment: You need a manifest but VS should add one for you.